# Populate WordPress Advanced Custom Fields with remote JSON in backend

Tags: json, wordpress

I have custom post types called "Products". and using the AFC(Advanced Custom Fields) plugin with this post type.
Below is what ACF has in fields group
- one filed called 'Product Description' as text area 
- three text fields called 'Feature 1, Feature 2,Feature 3'

What I want to achieve is to get the data from external JSON file and populate the above ACF fields in the backend. I did some research and found Wordpress offers wp_remote_get() function to request the remote file. But I have no clue where to begin with to use this function or any other approach to use external JSON and populate these fields. Will really appreciate it someone points me to the right direction or any tutorial that shows how to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: Is your JSON file on a separate domain or is it a url under your existing site?  Are you new to php development, need to know as to how much information will be necessary to help.

Comment: When do you want to populate these fields? As in do you want to populate them when each post is saved or all at once for all the posts that have been generated so far?

Comment: @Robert, Yes I'm new to Php development. JSON file reside on remote folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. View the working code below.

```
// Get JSON and Decode
$json_request = wp_remote_get( 'http://wp-test/test/data.json');

if( is_wp_error( $json_request ) ) {
    return false;
}    

$json_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $json_request );
$json_data = json_decode( $json_body );

// Create the new post and populate the fields
foreach( $json_data->products as $item ) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $desc = $item->content;
    $status = $item->status;


$new_post = array(
 'post_title' => $title,
 'post_content' => $desc,
 'post_status' => $status,
 'post_author' => $userID,
 'post_type' => 'products'
 );

$post_id = post_exists( $title );
if (!$post_id) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
```

}